# T is a matrix with spectral radius 1, $\hat{T}$=avarage asymptotic dynamics of T then it maps every generalized eigenvector to 0.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, linear-transformations

Let T be any square matrix whose spectral radius is 1. Let $\lambda \neq 1$ be any eigenvalue of T. Let
$\hat{T} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{T^n}{\| T^n\|} $. Let x be any generalized eigenvector of T corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $\hat{T}x=0$.

My attempt:
We can write $T= PJP^{-1}$ and hence $T^n= PJ^nP^{-1}$ for any n where P is an invertible Matrix having generalized eigenvectors $V_1,\dots , V_m$ as column vectors and J is the Jordan form.
Now any generalized eigen vector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ is in span of these V_i's. Hence suffices to look at action of $\hat{T}$ on these V_i. Further $V_i=Pe_i$ for some standard basis vector e_i. I computed the block matrix form of powers of J and then estimated it's norm. These computations are a bit tedious and I am not getting the feel of what's happening here. I have some rough idea using these computations. But is there any better and more concrete way?